# Example code to check parallelism of HSL solver MA97 in IPOPT

Tags: multithreading, matlab, mathematical-optimization, ipopt

I'm working on solving non-linear optimization problems. Currently I'm evaluating different algorithms to find out which one fits my problem best. I'm using MATLAB 2020b on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I currently got IPOPT with the HSL solvers up and running. My problem consists of a few hundred variables (~500 at the moment). Switching to MA97 didn't show any performance improvements. Probably my problem is too small? Nevertheless, I'd like to check if the parallelism of MA97 compared to e.g. MA27 is working properly, hence, if I compiled everything correctly.

Is there any sample problem where I can verify if MA97 is working multi-threaded but MA27 not?

Comment: Should be able to check whether OpenMP is being invoked.

Comment: Sadly I have troubles with installing perf. If I want to install perf and all its dependencies I get the error `E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-48-generic`

Comment: Can debug through the code? If you view the call stack, should see OpenMP methods (from libiomp/iomp) for the parallel case.

Comment: I don't have access to the code as is. I can only specify which linear solver ipopt uses in the background, hence, I have a line `sol = ipopt(...)`

Comment: Sure but you do need to have the OpenMP libs locally right? You can check if they are being used with GDB? Set a breakpoint on the shared object.

Comment: Yeah, I located the `libomp.so` file in `/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib`. I'm totally new to these debugging tools though. Do I run the code which calls ipopt with the (gdb) prefix? I have to note that I'm using MATLAB to call ipopt.

Comment: You shouldn't need any GDB prefix, I think you can set a breakpoint on the shared object itself, if not look at one of the methods in its interface and set your breakpoint there. It may prompt you that the shared object has not been load yet. It may actually be easier to just use a process monitor like top (or htop) to view your main process. top has a -H flag for checking threads.

Comment: I've tried to use htop (and top) but I don't find a way to check if openMP is working. The ipopt process only takes a few ms, hence, if the output in the bash is refreshed, the process is already finished.

Comment: You can set the refresh freq higher (I believe the flag is -d i.e. top -d 0.01 -n 1000). There should be some way you can pipe the outputs from top into a file and view if later.

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches suggested:

1. Try to debug from Matlab into the native code and see what IPOPT is calling into. This approach is tricky because Matlab itself uses OpenMP.
2. Use proc filesystem, if there are subdirectories under `/proc/self/tasks`, the process is multi-threaded. This approach has the same issues as above (Matlab backend will likely be using multi-threading).
3. Use environmental variables to limit the number of OpenMP threads (`OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`) and check for performance changes. Will need to measure this difference specifically around the call to IPOPT, as again, Matlab will be using OpenMP for its own functionality.

Matlab has a built-in profiler:

```
% start profiling
profile on

% your code ...

% launch profile viewer
profile viewer
```

Also, the IPOPT logs may be helpful. If the solver is multithreaded, there should be a difference between elapsed real-time and CPU time. This scales with parallelism, i.e

`CPU time ∝ threads count * elapsed real-time`

This is a rough approximation which is only valid up to the point you become resource-constrained on the number of threads.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! The first option doesn't work because IPOPT is a mex-file (compiled c-code) file which MATLAB can't profile into (same issue when using the profiler). For the second idea, if I invoke `dir /proc/self/task` to show the content of this folder, there are already several folders present after startup. If I set the `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1` I get a warning in the bash saying `OMP: Warning #96: Cannot form a team with 4 threads, using 1 instead.` but the process is as fast as without this setting (without the limit set, I don't get a warning)

Comment: Matlab can debug&&profile into a Mex file (see Mathworks documentation), there are configuration settings when you compile the Mex which need to be toggled on (assuming you have the ability to recompile the Mex). If you don't get any change in performance when changing the env variables, that could mean IPOPT is not running multithreaded OR you are running IPOPT out of process OR your process is not seeing the change in env variables. Print them from your process to verify.

Comment: The exact problem is, that the IPOPT mex file is a proprietary file which I cannot compile or re-compile. I get the ipopt.mexa64 as is. This is the main issue why I can't look deeper in it. Reading from MATLAB, `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is properly set to 4 and `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` is empty. The t_wall time is considerably lower than the t_proc. But this is also the case if I set  `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1` and `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` or if I use a linear solver which is not using any parallel threads at all (i.e. MA27).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already solved your problem. But I want to reply to help others. If you pass option linear_solver ma97 IPOPT should use HSL MA97 solver. I dont know how it can be done from MATLAB but if you add working directory "ipopt.opt" file IPOPT will read this file and apply specified options.
File content: (no equality sign)
linear_solver ma97

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).